# binding to array not working within vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get my head around vue.js but I seem to be missing something essential.

I have several boxes and I want them to act like an accordion (only one gets displayed; opening another box closes the previous one). This is my code:

```
<div id="app">

  <div class="block">
    <button v-on:click="mytoggle(0,$event)">block one</button>
    <div v-if="boxes[0]">
      <p>i am box number one</p>
      <p>i am box number one</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <button v-on:click="mytoggle(1,$event)">block two</button>
    <div v-if="boxes[1]">
      <p>i am box number two</p>
      <p>i am box number two</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <button v-on:click="mytoggle(2,$event)">block three</button>
    <div v-if="boxes[2]">
      <p>i am box number three</p>
      <p>i am box number three</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>

</div>
```

and the script:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    methods: {
        mytoggle: function (n, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // close all boxes
                this.boxes[i] = false;
            }
            this.boxes[n] = true; // open the corresponding box
            console.log(n);
        }
    },

    data: {
        boxes: [false,true,false]
    }
});
```

When the page is loaded, the second box gets displayed (which is correct, because the second element in the boxes array is true).

But clicking on the buttons doesn't change the boxes.array nor the display of the boxes. The log tells me, that the script as such seems to work because I get the correct value logged when I click the buttons.
So I suppose its something in the binding.
Can someone lead me on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">

  <div class="block">
    <button @click.prevent="mytoggle(0)">block one</button>
    <div v-show="boxes[0].show">
      <p>i am box number one</p>
      <p>i am box number one</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <button @click.prevent="mytoggle(1)">block two</button>
    <div v-show="boxes[1].show">
      <p>i am box number two</p>
      <p>i am box number two</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <button @click.prevent="mytoggle(2)">block three</button>
    <div v-show="boxes[2].show">
      <p>i am box number three</p>
      <p>i am box number three</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr/>

  <pre>{{ boxes | json}}</pre>

</div>
```

Vue:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        boxes: [{show:false},{show:true},{show:false}]
    },
    methods: {
        mytoggle: function (n) {  
            for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // close all boxes
                vm.boxes[i].show = false;
            }
            vm.boxes[n].show = true; // open the corresponding box
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/9a6bua6x/

EDIT:

You could also just change your `mytoggle` method to change array values using Vue's `$set`:

```
mytoggle: function (n, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // close all boxes
        this.boxes.$set(i, false);
    }
    this.boxes.$set(n, true); // open the corresponding box
    console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: That have no effect, because the data update is not being changed in the `boxes` variable. Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/m1byy7k3/1/) with `v-show` and some other litle changes, still not working

Comment: Interesting. Vue isn't binding the array values. It does work with an array of objects. I'll update the answer with a solution for you, even because most times we would work with array of objects, where you have a block object, with an id value, and a show value, or selected value...

Comment: I've been using vue for a while and I've never noticed a problem with arrays of primitive values. It seems like a bug to me

Comment: Same here. It doesn't make sense. Look at this very simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/Leqy66r8/

Comment: I'll report the issue :)

Comment: Nice! I'm curious about this behavior.

Comment: It is supposed to be some javascript limitation. https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: Yea, I saw that. Good investigation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$set` method, instead of directly change. [[ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats)]

Also, you could use a simpler workaround like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: 1
  },
  methods: {
    select (index) {
      this.selected = index
    },
    isSelected (index) {
      return this.selected === index
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.24/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="block">
    <button @click="select(0)">block one</button>
    <div v-show="isSelected(0)">
      <p>i am box number one</p>
      <p>i am box number one</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <button @click="select(1)">block two</button>
    <div v-show="isSelected(1)">
      <p>i am box number two</p>
      <p>i am box number two</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <button @click="select(2)">block three</button>
    <div v-show="isSelected(2)">
      <p>i am box number three</p>
      <p>i am box number three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```